# How to modify application shortcut property in Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: google-chrome, kali-linux

Today I installed **Kali Linux 2.0** after installing updates I installed **Google Chrome**. Now The problem is that I cannot access chrome command property in Kali Linux 2.0 nor in the **Top Bar** nor in the **Dash to Dock** . The **Kali Dev team** have changed the simple gnome to **gnome 3.14**. 
In early versions of Kali we right click on an application in **Top bar** and select property. where we were changing command.

> https://abraoximenes.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/screenshot-from-2013-05-21-202349.png

I need this for chrome because I want to run google-chrome as **standard user** while logged in as **root**.
I have created a user for chrome using....

```
useradd -m chromeuser
```

Now whenever i want to run chrome as standard user while logged in as root I run.

```
gksu -u chromeuser google-chrome
```

I want to add this line to chrome property command .

***My question is is there any way to modify application shortcut property in Kali Linux 2.0 (Gnome 3.14.1) using CLI?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Kali Linux 2.0, re-modifying flags for chromium became harder than old releases of Kali, or maybe impossible. For instance; old cracking techniques like we did in hexeditor by changing 'geteuid' to 'getppid' doesn't work anymore. Also folder hierarchy seems to be completely changed, for example the file `/opt/google/google-chrome/default` or `/opt/chromium/default` doesn't exist anymore.

So, to make the long story short, thing you wish to perform seems currently doest have a way out. But if you want, you can run chromium without sandbox flag checks by the code line below:

```
chromium --user-data-dir --disable-namespace-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox
```